# Plotly : R display hovertext for ymin as well as for ymax

Tags: r, plotly, hover, ribbon

When using the function "Compare data on hover" for a plotly ribbon plot, only the ymax value is displayed.

A sample tibble is as follows

```
tib <- tibble(year = 1:4, min = rnorm(4), max = 15+rnorm(4))  

plot_ly(tib, x= ~year) %>% 
add_ribbons(ymin = ~ min, ymax = ~ max, line = list(color = "lightgrey"),
              markers = list(color = "lightgrey"),
              fillcolor = "rgba(7, 164, 181, 0.2)", name = "95% region", 
              hovertemplate = paste( "Rate: %{y:.1f}<br>year: %{x} </br>"))
```

The output is
[image]

How do I display the ymin hovertext as well?

Comment: The `ymin` value is displayed in the lower part of the plot.

Comment: I was looking for the minimum Rate ymin value, which is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is to disable this tooltip and add two lines:

```
plot_ly(tib, x= ~year) %>% 
  add_ribbons(ymin = ~ min, ymax = ~ max, line = list(color = "lightgrey"),
              fillcolor = "rgba(7, 164, 181, 0.2)", name = "95% region",
              hoverinfo = "none") %>%
  add_lines(y = ~ min,
            hovertemplate = "Rate: %{y:.1f}<br>year: %{x} </br>") %>%
  add_lines(y = ~ max,
            hovertemplate = "Rate: %{y:.1f}<br>year: %{x} </br>")
```

Comment: Thanks Stephane.  Your code has enlightened my knowledge and helped me with my task.

Answer (score 0):

Mega late to the party, but because I had the same problem, I solved it by adding a `text` to the ribbons and set the hoverinfo to text:

```r
library(plotly)
library(tibble)

tib <- tibble(year = 1:4, min = rnorm(4), max = 15 + rnorm(4))  

plot_ly(tib, x = ~year) %>% 
  add_ribbons(ymin = ~ min, ymax = ~ max, line = list(color = "lightgrey"),
              text = ~ paste0("[", round(min, 1L), ",", round(max, 1L), "]"),
              markers = list(color = "lightgrey"),
              fillcolor = "rgba(7, 164, 181, 0.2)", name = "95% region", 
              hovertemplate = "Rate: %{text}<br>year: %{x} </br>")
```